# running loop through two functions taking each others output as input

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, function, loops

I have two functions, say

```
def f1(arr,k):
    #does something here with elements of array arr starting from index k and returns i..
    #EDIT: we don't need value1 from f1, 
    i=k
    while arr[i]==0:
        i=i+1
    return i
```

and another function

```
def f2(arr,arr2,k):
   # does something here with elements of array arr starting from index k (k is output from function f1)...
    #EDIT: following is the code for f2:
    pr=0
    if arr[k]==1:
        i=k
        while (pr<10 and pr>-10) and (arr2[i+1]!=2):
            pr=pr+(arr2[i+1]-arr2[i])
        i=i+1

    if arr[k]==2:
        i=k
        while (pr<10 and pr>-10) and (arr[i+1]!=1):
            pr=pr+(arr2[i]-arr2[i+1])
            i=i+1
    return i+1, pr
```

This output i+1 is again used for function f1, we do this till the we reach the end of array.

I can't seem to get the logic on how to do this.

I define a function

```
def final(arr):
    x=0 #starting index
    #need to use above two functions to return value2 as a list for each iteration...
```

Can someone provide some direction?

## EDIT: After doing what @AlexForGill answered, I am getting Index Out of Bounds error for function f2

```
def final(arr,arr2):
x=0
plist=[]
while x < len(arr)-1:
    x = f1(arr, x)
    if x >= len(arr)-1: # guard clause for applying second function
        break
    x, value2 = f2(arr,arr2, x)
    plist.append(value2)
return plist
```

Comment: So you don't need `value1` at all?

Comment: Apparently, I realized I don't need value1.

Comment: I suggest you to put `f1` in `f2`, and loop f2 if `f1` has nothing to do with the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would the following work for you?

```
def final(arr):
    x = 0
    accumulator = []
    while (x < len(arr)):
        x, value1 = f1(arr, x)
        if (x >= len(arr)): # guard clause for applying second function
            break
        x, value2 = f2(arr, x)
        accumulator.append(value2)
    return accumulator
```

The `while` loop alternates between calling `f1` and `f2`. The result of `f1` is the updated index, which is assigned to `x`. This value is then passed into `f2`, which also returns the updated index which is again assigned to `x`.

`value2` is then appended to the accumulator list which is returned at the end of the loop.

Comment: Could you provide a short explanation?

Comment: Nice, but I think this should also collect `value2` in a list.

Comment: @tobias_k you're right - I missed that comment in the question

Comment: @AmanArora I've added an explanation and a list accumulator for gathering all of the `value2`s

Comment: Thank you.
But I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when function f1 cannot find an index near the end of the list. (according to some conditions described in the function)

Comment: @AmanArora without knowing the body of `f1` I can't tell what's wrong, could you update the question?

Comment: After doing all the above edits and solving all issues, I found out that plist has only 1 element.